# StompSession.subscribe how to wait until client is subscribed?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-websocket, completable-future

I would like to subscribe `WebSocketStompClient` on some topic but I need to wait till the subscription was completed (stop the thread). Unfortunately the `StompSession.subscribe` doesn't return completable future so I don't know how to do it. Could anyone help me here?